# Service written in c# not working after installing it

Tags: c#, service, windows-server-2008

A windows service written in c# which actually interacts with MS Word works fine when run in debug mode..or running it from the command prompt..

But it's not working after installing it as a service. The account which runs the service is an Administrator (local).

Server 2008 R2...never had a problem before using in 2003

Comment: can you post some code snippets?

Comment: what do the windows logs say?

Comment: Are you using an interop assembly to interact with Office?

Comment: assembly is there...as I said it works fine if I run through command prompt

Comment: @Mike, when you say "run from the command prompt" what does that mean?

Comment: when I run the exe...its a console app....

Comment: Wait a sec. Are you sure that you wrote Windows Service? and are you sure that, you are trying to install with installutil.exe /i yourexe ?

Comment: yes..I installed it many times and it was working for past two years on win2003...now I am trying to do the same thing in 2008R2.

Comment: when I run the exe with arg -d...I have DebugStart();...

Comment: it works fine if have it in Debug mode

Comment: did you try my answer? using eventlog

Answer (score 3):

The best way to understand "why my service is not running?" is using

```
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

in **On Start**, **Your Main Method**, etc.. event.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Server 2008 R2, services that you build in .Net Framework that need access to the file system in order to run need to have proper privileges to run. In my case, I needed to install the service, open the Services window, stop my service, right-click and edit the properties of the service to use an administrator account when running. Once I did that, the service started working as intended.

Now, that might not be the best thing to do all the time, so you will probably want to define a custom account on the system that has the least amount of privileges required to execute your service.

Answer (score 0):

Does the service account have ["Log on as a service"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28WS.10%29.aspx) rights?

Comment: yes..it does...that where I set Admin(local) account to run the service

Answer (score 0):

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args)